# Got a new monitor and unsure about the warning that pops up on it

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi

So recently, I bought my self a brand new LG 34UM68, and when I set it up, a pop-up appeared saying roughly along the lines of,
"(Caution) Be sure to use a supplied display port and an HDMI cable."

Now, I'm rather new to the double monitor scene, so I'm not sure if using just the supplied HDMI cable for the monitor that came from the box WITHOUT the DisplayPort is okay or do I have to grab one? If it's any help, my second monitor is on a VGA display and it's the ASUS VG248QE 24 inch 1920x1080 Monitor.

Any and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like your using a cable for a revision lower than the monitor supports

Comment: My 27UL650-W does this as well, even though I'm using the supplied DisplayPort cable. Is it possible that this is a generic caution message, and is not caused by any acutal issues with the cable that were detected by the monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions mean that you have to *either* use the supplied HDMI or DisplayPort cable. It means that they don't want you to use a 3rd party cable (which would work fine, but manufacturers always want to play safe).

Displayport might give you a slightly better quality, although 2560 x 1080 should be fine for HDMI.

Comment: Thank you so much for that! I was worried I had to use both since it said AND.